# Entity Framework Code First: Table Splitting and Custom Fields

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

Let me start by saying I would change this database model if I could, but it is how one of our OTS solutions was designed to accommodate multiple customers and to allow custom configurations.

That said, I am using EF with a code first approach and want to create multiple entities to map to a single table that is essentially being used as a Custom Field Data Table. The table has a schema like this:

```
ID   EmployeeID   Category   Field1   Field2   Field3
1    1            Education  NYU      B.A.     2008
2    1            Retirement 401k     200.00   2054
3    2            Education  GWU      M.A.     2003
4    2            Retirement Roth     140.00   2048
```

There's also another table somewhere that explains what Field1, Field2, Field3 mean (e.g. University, Degree, Graduation Year for education, and Investment, Biweekly Contribution, Retirement Eligibility Year).

The current configuration is not expected to ever change (for our company), so I would rather map this single Custom Field Table to two separate entities: EducationData and RetirementData that have intelligently named properties like "University", "Degree"...etc. instead of "Field1", "Field2"...etc.

Any recommendations on how to go about this? Ideally I'd like to configure it as part of the EF model so I can query off the new fields, but I'm open to suggestions.

```
context.Employees.EducationData(x => x.University == "GWU");
```

rather than

```
context.Employees.CustomFieldData(x => x.Category == "Education" && x.Field1 == "GWU")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that I suppose you could try doing this is using TPH:

1. Create some types

   ```
   abstract class CustomFieldData
   {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
       public string Field1 { get; set; }
       public string Field2 { get; set; }
       public string Field3 { get; set; }
   }

   class EducationData : CustomFieldData
   {
       public string School { 
           get { return Field1; }  // you could use custom conversion here
           set { Field1 = value; }
       // similar for other fields
   }

   class RetirementData : CustomFieldData
   {
       // similar to EducationData
   }
   ```
2. Customize the [mapping for TPH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#2.4)

   ```
   modelBuilder.Entity<CustomFieldData>()  
       .Map<EducationData>(m => m.Requires("Category").HasValue("Education"))  
       .Map<RetirementData>(m => m.Requires("Category").HasValue("Retiremen"));
   ```
3. Ignore fields in derived classes that were mapped from FieldX, since you can't have multiple properties mapped to the same database column.

   ```
   modelBuilder.Entity<EducationData>().Ignore(t => t.School);
   // similar for other properties
   ```

Comment: That pretty much did it. Thank you!